# How to go cheap way (train/bus/flight) from New York city to Oklahoma city (Stillwater)?

Tags: usa, budget, tips-and-tricks

I am Asian. I am planning to go from New York airport (Laguardia or John F. Kennedy) to the Oklahoma City at Stillwater (near Oklahoma State University) through Train/bus/flight.

Let me say, I want to go with cheap budget.

Can you help me the approximate cost? Which among train/bus/flight would save my cost?

Thanks

Comment: I was about to do a couple of searches for you, but you obviously have access to the internet. Why don't you spend a few minutes looking? There is only one passenger rail line in the US - Amtrak. There are a couple of bus companies, and airlines are in abundance. Taking the bus will be the cheapest, but the most painfully slow - it is 1450 miles (2320km) from JFK to Stillwater, OK and it's about 22 hours driving time. Probably double that by bus because they stop everywhere.

Comment: @FreeMan, I had idea about trainline in US. However, I got to get search in Amtrak as you suggested and found it costs around $200. Thanks

Comment: Amtrak probably isn't very quick, either, and the times tend to be abysmal, but if price is your only consideration, there you go! You may want to watch prices for a few days/weeks. Flight prices change regularly (weekly, daily), but I'm not sure about trains or buses here in the US.

Comment: @FreeMan, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/New-York/Oklahoma-City) is usually the best bet for this sort of planning, at least in North America & Europe.

Comment: The thing is ground transport generally involves living costs that drive it above the cost of air transport even if the tickets start out cheaper.  Even when your destination is someplace small you're usually better off flying to the closest place with plenty of air traffic and only going ground for the last bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flying seems IMO the best option. One way flights start at around $220 (United from LaGuardia)

A bus like Greyhound is cheaper (starting at $140) but it'll take you more than 36 hours and you have to account for buying food and sleep & back recovery. 36 hours in a bus are no joke.

Train is not competitive both in terms of duration (40+ hours) and price ($250+). You could consider a sleeper but this are more expensive than a business class flight.

If you are really adventures you can research some of the "Chinatown busses" but I don't think this will help much in this case. (e.g. https://www.chinatown-bus.org/)

The cheapest option would carpooling. That works well in Europe (BlaBla car for example) but is still in its infancy in the US and splicing a trip like this together would require serious luck.